# $d^{1/3}$ badly approx. $\iff$ $d^{2/3}$ is badly approx.

Tags: diophantine-approximation

> Let $d$ be an integer, that is not a cube of any integer. Show that $d^{1/3}$  is badly approximable iff $d^{2/3}$ is also.

Badly approximable means that, there is a contant $C$ s.t.

$\lvert \beta-\frac pq\rvert<\frac{C}{q^2}$ holds for only finitely many rationals $p/q$ with $p,q$ relatively prime

I already proved that,

$\beta$ is badly approximable iff $n\beta$ and $\frac{1}{\beta}$ are badly aprrox.  for $n\in\mathbb N$

(There is a theorem which states that, a real number $\beta$ is badly approximable if the sequence $\{a_i\}_i$, where $a_i$ are the numbers in the continued fraction of $\beta$, i.e. $\beta=[a_0,a_1,\dots]$, is bounded.)

What is the difference between saying that

$d^{1/3}$ badly approx. $\iff$ $d^{2/3}$ is badly approx.

And

$\beta$ badly approx. $\iff$ $\beta^2$ is badly approx.

Comment: When you write "for $n\in\mathbb N$", so you mean "for all $n\in\mathbb N$" or "for some $n\in\mathbb N$"?

Comment: @HenningMakholm  For any nonzero $n\in\mathbb N$, (it is fix) $\beta$ is approx. iff $n\beta$ is approx. I already showed this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By what you say you have already proved, $\root3\of d$ badly approximable implies $d^{-1/3}$ badly approximable implies $dd^{-1/3}$ badly approximable, but there's your $d^{2/3}$.

Comment: why is the product badly approx. ?

Comment: That's one of the things you said you had already proved – if $\beta$ is b.a., then so is $n\beta$ for integer $n$. Just let $n=d$ and $\beta=d^{-1/3}$.